# Is there a way to auto-fill the reference field in Xero when I begin a new quote?

Tags: webhooks, xero-api

99% of our quotes in Xero are generated using the same value in the 'Reference' field. We have to look this up, and copy-paste it each time we make a new quote. I want to auto-fill the reference field when I visit the 'New quote' page, which is "https://go.xero.com/app/!v!s-w/quotes/".

I've tried using a Tampermonkey script to edit the webpage element, which works perfectly when I load the new quote page. However, the field itself mustn't actually populate because the value disappears when I click on the field or save the new quote.

I've tried researching Xero API to trigger a webhook when I load a new quote page, to create a new Zapier workflow to update the reference field, but I'm not skilled enough to know where to start.

I know it's likely a real simple solution so I feel bad asking, but I've been trying for a few days now and hopefully someone has a quick fix, it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Could you please post your Tampermonkey script?